# firebase change textContent of button using foreach

Tags: javascript, foreach, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use a foreach loop to access my firebase database and populate 5 buttons with the answers taken down.  The error that is being thrown is

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. file:///Users/michaelheneghan/Desktop/CS353C/JudgingPage.html:229:69
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:200:357
ka@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:276
ka@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:270
ka@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:32:467
R@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:83:381
forEach@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:200:327
file:///Users/michaelheneghan/Desktop/CS353C/JudgingPage.html:226:33
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:202:714
gc@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:52:166
cc@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:30:218
dc@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:29:1261
Kb@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:221:289
[native code]
Ld@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:189:253
[native code]
Ld@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:179:366
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:177:282
zh@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:171:466
onmessage@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:170:247

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByTagName('button')[counter].textContent = data.child("ChosenAnswer").val()')
```

I've tried various ways and when I print to console the correct information is being shown so I know I'm giving it the right path.

I've tried slowing it down with a setInterval function, incase it's an issue with the callback method but still no change.  GameRef is literally a variable storing a number relating to what game number they are in.

```
var GameRef = localStorage.getItem("GameRef"); //get the game reference from previous page to pull data down from database
var counter = 0; 
var vals = "";
var trsfAns = "";
var check = "";
console.log(GameRef);

var ref = new Firebase("https://cau-maynooth.firebaseio.com/Game/Game " + GameRef); // Store a link to location of current game
console.log("Ref is " + ref);

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) { // Loop through each submitted answer and display on buttons for user choice
          var name = data.child("ChosenAnswer").val();
          console.log(name);
            document.getElementsByTagName('button')[counter].textContent = data.child("ChosenAnswer").val();
            counter++; // increment counter to display snapshot data on next button

        });
});
```

Counter is originally set to 0 and the node above has exactly 5 children. I've tried storing the info as a variable and entering that but get the same error.

Here's how the data is stored, I'm trying to access and display the value of "ChosenAnswer":

```
    {
  "Game" : {
"Game 1" : {
  "-KF8s5IxnxgRabSEyrVk" : "Option number 3",
  "-KF8s7XSeocBwiJQDgY5" : "Option number 1",
  "-KF8sAB-9c74mEaDLlB-" : "Option number 4",
  "-KF8sBLAo8FozBOoiptS" : "Option number 1",
  "-KF8sDBtZ9lvcNXeuxI8" : "Option number 5"
},
"Game 2" : {
  "-KFQnS7qCqFEgRRGZ2NV" : {
    "ChosenAnswer" : "Option number 5",
    "ID" : "5f9ff985-fc3b-48d7-83b4-e28751c1ba66"
  },
  "-KFQo38x_7MlKMHBUB9G" : {
    "ChosenAnswer" : "Option number 5",
    "ID" : "5f9ff985-fc3b-48d7-83b4-e28751c1ba66"
  },
  "-KFQoJ2HT0pioUs8kLgL" : {
    "ChosenAnswer" : "Option number 1",
    "ID" : "5f9ff985-fc3b-48d7-83b4-e28751c1ba66"
  },
  "-KFQocb61r3LVg_cs8HY" : {
    "ChosenAnswer" : "Option number 1",
    "ID" : "5f9ff985-fc3b-48d7-83b4-e28751c1ba66"
  },
  "-KFQooYUTsf_zgKt9xwQ" : {
    "ChosenAnswer" : "Option number 6",
    "ID" : "5f9ff985-fc3b-48d7-83b4-e28751c1ba66"
  }
```

I know it will probably be something really elementary that I don't know about Firebase but I'm new to it and was hoping someone could lend a hand.

It'd be greatly appreciated!

*************************EDITED************************************

Originally I only stored the chosen answer on Firebase and the code below worked. I changed it to include their UID as I want to be able to allocated coins etc to a user if they win a game and now it isn't working(see above).

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) { // Loop through each submitted answerand display on buttons for user choice
            document.getElementsByTagName('button')[counter].textContent = data.val();
            counter++; // increment counter to display snapshot data on next button

        });
});

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  onclick="selectedAnswer(1)"><label id="s1" for="subOpt1"></label></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block"  onclick="selectedAnswer(2)"><label id="s2" for="subOpt2"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  onclick="selectedAnswer(3)"><label id="s3" for="subOpt3"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block"  onclick="selectedAnswer(4)"><label id="s4" for="subOpt4"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block"  onclick="selectedAnswer(5)"><label id="s5" for="subOpt5"></button>
```

Comment: Include the entire stack trace with non-minified libs. Also indicate how you verified the various parts aren't undefined--getElementsByTagName('button') and the following [counter]. (hint: one of them is). Possibly you're trying to access dom elements before the dom is ready. Hard to say without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Kato, I've edited my post to include everything I think you wanted. Let me know if I've committed anything and thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Just to test your theory of the DOM not being ready I place my code within this: var docLoaded = setInterval(function () {
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(docLoaded);
        /*
            My foreach loop went in here
        */
    }
}, 100);  But it still produces the same error